# My IT manager says rMBP is not satisfied ISO27001

Tags: macos, iso27001

My company computer is using MS Windows and I myself as a software engineer I would recommend my developer team to use OSX since it is hassle least than Linux/Unix based OS. When I propose the computer spec to IT department.

I would like the company to support us for this because my developers they are using mixed up and fancy OS with fancy IDE from everywhere! but for I myself is fine I am using my own and my manager resolve this situation by placing my name in other depart apart from ISO27001 area.

I had proposed rMBP spec and extended 27'' 2 monitors. It can last for 10 years with this spec and expensive. They rejects my request with reason that rMBP is not fit to ISO27001.

I think ISO27001 is not a problem, but when company buy. It needs to buy for all employees!

How can rMBP fit to ISO27001?

Comment: You've asked 2 very different questions. Your ssh question is out of place with the rest of your post.

Answer (score 1):

The standard does not specify any technology, neither does it ban any technology. It specifies how the organisation manages its security.

If your organisation's security policies mean that this technology is not allowed, then it's not allowed.